# Get event when window has been closed

Tags: bash, window-manager, window, xdotool

I try to automate some repetitive tasks with `xdotool`. In one task I want to [automatically save a website to a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612485/save-firefox-webpage-by-xdotool/612510#612510). While printing on Firefox there is a progress bar which looks like this:

[image]

I want to start a new task when the printing window has been closed (it closes automatically after saving the file). My current workaround is to use something like `sleep 10` to prevent the next task from beginning to early. How can I get the event that the printing window has been closed?

(I am a Linux Mint user.)

**Bash script**

```
# Get window id (Firefox)
FIREFOX_ID=$(xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" | head -n1)
# Activate window (Firefox)
xdotool windowactivate "$FIREFOX_ID"
# Open print dialog
xdotool key "ctrl+p"
# Get window id (print dialog)
DIALOG_ID=$(xdotool search --name "Print") # Change name to your language
# Activate window (print dialog)
xdotool windowactivate "$DIALOG_ID"
# Click "Print" button
xdotool mousemove 1240 790 click 1 # Change coordinates to yours
```

Comment: Do you know of the `wait` command? Please also add some code example.

Comment: @Fiximan I added some code. No, I don't know `wait.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just check for the "Printing" window. Take your code as above, and let's focus on the moment you click print:

```
# Click "Print" button
xdotool mousemove 1240 790 click 1 # Change coordinates to yours
```

After that, you will have a "Printing" ("Drucken") progress box appear. Let's just check for its existence before moving on:

```
#sleep 1 second to allow printing to start - a pure safety measure
sleep 1
#check for printing progress window until failed
while (xdotool search --name "Printing") ; do
  sleep 0.1
done
<next command>
```

I.e. as long as there is a "printing" dialogue, do the `while`-loop will run and block the next command.

---

Regarding the `wait` command:

This does not apply here, as `xdotool` activates processes outside the shell script. Nevertheless it is simply used to ensure that a process is being waited for to finish:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 do_some_command & wait
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to get the process id of the active window with `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid` and then activate the `ẁait` command? (BTW: Your code works like charm! Thank you!)

Comment: Actually your codes print every 0.1 seconds the output of the command `xdotool search --name "Printing"` to the console. To prevent this I use `xdotool search --name "Printing" > /dev/null 2>&1` instead.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider `wait` is limited to the current shell, so no, you could not wait for some process not part of the script. Yes, dumping the output is a good point.